# Is it ever possible to create a reference to element of array of struct?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, reference

Given an `Array` with `struct`

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    struct Card {
        var flag: String = ""
    }
    
    var cards = Array<Card>()
    cards.append(Card())
```

The following operation will NOT modify original array element

```swift
    // A copy is created.
    var cardCopy = cards[0]
    
    // Will NOT modify cards[0] 
    cardCopy.flag = "modify0"
    
    print(cards[0].flag)
```

The following operation will modify original array element

```swift
    // We can modify cards[0] by
    cards[0].flag = "modify"

    print(cards[0].flag)
```

However, it isn't efficient in the sense, we need to perform indexing access each time. Imagine

```swift
    cards[0].flag0 = "modify"
    cards[0].flag1 = "modify"
    cards[0].flag2 = "modify"
    cards[0].flag3 = "modify"
    ...
```

**Is there a way, we can create reference to element of array of struct?** So that we can write

```
// How to create a reference to cards[0]?
var cardReference = ...
```

```swift
    cardReference.flag0 = "modify"
    cardReference.flag1 = "modify"
    cardReference.flag2 = "modify"
    cardReference.flag3 = "modify"
    ...
```

One of the possibilities is to replace `struct` with `class`. But, I would like to explore other alternative, before doing so.

Comment: If you need to modify your Card instance a lot maybe you should make it a class instead or create a new instance with new values and replace the whole object in the array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you. I would like to explore other possible alternatives (possible to create a reference?), before converting it from struct to class.

Comment: You cannot turn a value type into a reference type. As others have pointed out, `inout` is as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that using a function to make your changes and pass the `Card` struct by reference like this:

```
func update(card: inout Card) {
    card.flag0 = "modify"
    card.flag1 = "modify"
    card.flag2 = "modify"
    card.flag3 = "modify"
}

var cards = Array<Card>()
cards.append(Card())

update(card: &cards[0])
```

or even better by using a mutating function in `Card` type and pass as a closure your changes like that:

```
struct Card {
    var flag0: String = ""
    var flag1: String = ""
    var flag2: String = ""
    var flag3: String = ""
    
    mutating func update(block: (inout Card) -> Void) {
        block(&self)
    }
}
    
var cards = Array<Card>()
cards.append(Card())

cards[0].update {
    $0.flag0 = "modify"
    $0.flag1 = "modify"
    $0.flag2 = "modify"
    $0.flag3 = "modify"
}
```

**Update**: To make the second approach even more reusable, you can define a protocol like this:

```
protocol Updatable {
    mutating func update(block: (inout Self) -> Void)
}

extension Updatable {
    mutating func update(block: (inout Self) -> Void) {
        block(&self)
    }
}
```

and make `Card` struct conform to it:

```
struct Card: Updatable {
    var flag0: String = ""
    var flag1: String = ""
    var flag2: String = ""
    var flag3: String = ""
}
```

Then you can use it just like above.

Comment: I really like this trick of making the struct generally self-updatable; I can't believe I've never thought of that. :)

Comment: I'd like to include this idea in my book (attributed to you of course); please let me know if that's okay.

Comment: @matt I did some research about when I first saw something like this and found this https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/9b4aac87e7f88c80e932ba3c843252df. So, for me it's OK of course, but to be fair this wasn't entirely my idea.

Comment: Well, your idea here is not really taken from that gist, so I still think you get the credit.

Comment: @matt well, yes it's like another usage of the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, since `Array` is a `struct` and `struct`s are value types.

What you need is reference type behaviour, so you should convert your `struct` to a `class`.

Another solution for modifying several properties of a value type in one go is to create a `mutating` function that does that and calling that on the array element.

```
struct Card {
    var flag: String = ""
    var flag2 = ""

    mutating func update(flag: String, flag2: String) {
        self.flag = flag
        self.flag2 = flag2
    }
}

var cards = [Card(flag: "a", flag2: "b")]
cards[0].update(flag: "b", flag2: "c")
```