# How can I change the element in an array of struct

Tags: swift

I have an array of struct 'Pair' (Data) and I want to change the element in the array if some condition is met. I have followed the documentation https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html and created a 'setValue' method with `mutating`

But when I debug the code, I see the value of the `pair` variable get changed. But the array 'data?.pairs' does not get changed to the new value `'Point(1,2)`.  Can you please tell what am I missing?

```
public struct Data {
 var pairs: [Pair<Point>]
}
var array = data?.pairs ?? []
for index in 0..<array.count {
    var pair = data?.pairs[index]
                  
    if /* some test */ {
       print ("Found match")
       pair?.setValue(Point(1,2))   // `pair` is updated, but data?.paris[index] is not updated.
    }
}

struct Pair<Value: Comparable>{
    var key: Value
    var value: Value

    init(_ key: Value, _ value: Value) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }

    mutating func setValue(_ value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but you should choose another name to your structure. `Data` is a native Swift type (Foundation).

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485959/6791677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pair` is a struct, so value semantics apply. This means that here, you made a copy of each item in `data.pairs`:

```
var pair = data?.pairs[index]
```

And you are changing the copies, not the originals.

One way to solve this is to assign the changed copies back to `data.pairs`:

```
if /* some test */ {
   print ("Found match")
   pair?.setValue(Point(1,2))
   data?.pairs[index] = pair // here!
}
```

Or, don't make a copy in the first place:

```
if /* some test */ {
   print ("Found match")
   data?.pairs[index].setValue(Point(1,2))
}
```

Or, make `Pair` a class, so reference semantics apply, and you won't be making copies.

Comment: or simply `data?.pairs[index].value = Point(1, 2)`

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper for your detailed explanation. I have a followed up question. So I have an array to keep track of all the Data (a struct) that i want to modify.  When I do 'myArray.append(Data)' , i think all the elements in the 'myArray' is making a copy of the Data. So when I iterate the myArray and make changes to 'Data', it is also making a copy. How can I store `reference ` of Data when append to an array (myArray)?

Comment: @hap497 If you modify the data without taking it out of the array, like `dataArray[index1].pairs[index2].value = ...`, then you won't be making a copy. It's only when you put a struct on the right of `=`, or when you pass it into a function that you'll be copying it. If you keep it on the left, then you'll be fine. Alternatively, apply the first approach I showed, and copy whatever you copied, back to the data array.

Comment: @hap497 If you want to store references though, just make `Data` a class.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, arrays and structs in Swift are value types, so at the moment

```
var pair = data?.pairs[index]
```

the `pair` is a copy of an array item value, and has no relation to the original array.